# Why does the (!(feof(sp)) && end) never evaluate to true?

Tags: c, file, while-loop, directory, fread

I tried to create a program that compares between 2 files and checks if the second file exist in the first file.
The function r_scan gets into an endless loop.
I tried to debug the program and follow the output of (!(feof(sp)) && end) but I still didn't understand why is it happening.

This is my code:

```cpp
   int r_scan(char* virus_address, char* scaned_address)
    {
        //INIT
        char v = ' ', s = ' ';
        int end = 1, i = 0;
        long seek = 0;
        FILE* vp = NULL;
        FILE* sp = NULL;
        //Open th5e files.
        vp = fopen(virus_address, "rb");
        sp = fopen(scaned_address, "rb");
        fseek(vp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fseek(sp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        //pre scanning
        seek = 0;
        //Check if the file infected.
        while (!(feof(sp)) && end)
        {           
            fread(&s, 1, 1, sp);

            if (v == s)
            {
                v = fgetc(vp);
            }
            else
            {
                seek++;
                fseek(vp, 0, SEEK_SET);
                fseek(sp, seek, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&v, 1, 1, vp);
            }
            if (v == EOF)
            {
                end = 0;
            }
        }
    fclose(vp);
    fclose(sp);
    return end;
}
```

Comment: "Virus scanner" :D

Comment: What does "pre scaning" with `fread(&s, 1, 1, sp);` mean?

Comment: nothing i just forgot to change it.

Comment: Mu suggestion is to minimize your code first, e,g, leave just one loop that read two files byte-by-byte untill reach the end of at least one of file. Check, debug if needed, and then add other features.

Comment: OK but i still want to know why it doesn't work. And I'm not sure that I able to minimize is more than it right now

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Also you ***really*** want to add error checking to all relevant function calls. Consider "*relevant*" at least those function calls which might fail to return a value the code uses afterwards. Error checking is debugging for free. Simply assuming such a call wouldn't fail is naive and could cost you a lot of time and even worth energy.

Comment: The debugger doesn't tell me nothing. The while loop just keep running till I press ctrl + c @alk

Comment: Hint: `fgetc` returns `int` not `char`.

Comment: Ye, I forgot to change it in the if (v == s). But believe me that i tried everything and it still doesn't work

Comment: EOF is a int and -1, on platform where a char is unsgined, v ==EOF will never be true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page of `fseek` says:

> A successful call to the fseek() function clears the end-of-file indicator

When your program loops, `fseek(sp, seek, SEEK_SET);` is called before `feof(sp)` which is why `feof` always returns 0. And because you are not testing return value of `fread(&s, 1, 1, sp);` your program loops forever.